# How can I make the Logstash TCP input to separate the messages that it listens on a TCP port?

Tags: tcp, logstash, node-red

I want to send data to `Logstash` using the `TCP protocol`. And to send the data I'm using the `Node-RED`. A simple configuration for doing that looks like this:

[image: Sending TCP messages with the Node-RED]

In the `Logstash` folder, I created a file called `nodered.conf` with the following content:

```
input {
    tcp {
        port => "3999"
    }   
}

output {
        stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Right now, I just want to print on my screen the information that the `Logstash` is receiving. That's why I used `stdout { codec => rubydebug }` on my output.

So, inside the `Logstash` folder, I started the `Logstash` with the following command:

```
bin/logstash -f nodered.conf --config.reload.automatic
```

The problem is that all the messages that I send to `Logstash` with the `Node-RED` are aggregated into a single message. For example, if I inject 5 messages with the `Node-RED` into my `TCP port 3999`, after redeploying the `Node-RED` I receive the following content on my `Logstash` terminal:

```
user@computer:/home/Dados/ELK/logstash-5.4.0$ bin/logstash -f nodered.conf --config.reload.automatic
Sending Logstash's logs to /home/Dados/ELK/logstash-5.4.0/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2017-05-29T15:14:52,388][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Starting pipeline {"id"=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>4, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>5, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>500}
[2017-05-29T15:14:52,417][INFO ][logstash.inputs.tcp      ] Starting tcp input listener {:address=>"0.0.0.0:3999"}
[2017-05-29T15:14:52,430][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Pipeline main started
[2017-05-29T15:14:52,513][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
{
    "@timestamp" => 2017-05-29T18:19:33.277Z,
          "port" => 54316,
      "@version" => "1",
          "host" => "127.0.0.1",
       "message" => "hellohellohellohellohello"
}
```

And I actually would like to see something like this without having to redeploy:

```
user@computer:/home/Dados/ELK/logstash-5.4.0$ bin/logstash -f nodered.conf --config.reload.automatic
Sending Logstash's logs to /home/Dados/ELK/logstash-5.4.0/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2017-05-29T15:27:24,168][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Starting pipeline {"id"=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>4, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>5, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>500}
[2017-05-29T15:27:24,191][INFO ][logstash.inputs.tcp      ] Starting tcp input listener {:address=>"0.0.0.0:3999"}
[2017-05-29T15:27:24,200][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Pipeline main started
[2017-05-29T15:27:24,260][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
{
    "@timestamp" => 2017-05-29T18:27:48.394Z,
          "port" => 54518,
      "@version" => "1",
          "host" => "127.0.0.1",
       "message" => "hello"
}
{
    "@timestamp" => 2017-05-29T18:27:51.657Z,
          "port" => 54546,
      "@version" => "1",
          "host" => "127.0.0.1",
       "message" => "hello"
}
{
    "@timestamp" => 2017-05-29T18:27:58.691Z,
          "port" => 54600,
      "@version" => "1",
          "host" => "127.0.0.1",
       "message" => "hello"
}
{
    "@timestamp" => 2017-05-29T18:28:06.330Z,
          "port" => 54656,
      "@version" => "1",
          "host" => "127.0.0.1",
       "message" => "hello"
}
{
    "@timestamp" => 2017-05-29T18:28:14.347Z,
          "port" => 54682,
      "@version" => "1",
          "host" => "127.0.0.1",
       "message" => "hello"
}
```

The conclusion is that I don't know how to make the `Logstash` interpret each message as a unique one instead of concatenating everything that it receives. I've tried using different codecs in my `nodered.conf` file but I didn't succeed. Does anyone know how can I make the `Logstash` see every message that it listens on a TCP port as a single one?

Comment: try adding a new line char to the end of the message ("hello\n" in the inject node)

Comment: @hardillb: Good idea... But it didn't work :/. In the context of my example the message that I receive after adding "hello\n" in the inject node is: ("message" => "hello\\nhello\\nhello\\nhello\\nhello\\n"). I guess the Node-RED is adding a second "\" with the string automatically....

Comment: My mistake, you can't add a new line to the inject node, you have to include a function node to add "/n" to the end of the string (as mentioned at the end of the inject node info bar)

Comment: It worked!! I've just added a function node concatenating my string with \n and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Cool, I'll add a proper answer with the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Node-RED is just sending a stream of bytes via the TCP node Logstash has nothing to indicate the end of the record.

As mentioned in the comments you can add a new line char (/n) to the end of the string using a function node and this should signal to Logstash that that is a whole record.

```
msg.payload += "\n";
return msg;
```